# Is that possible to connect windows application (C#) through domain IP and port

Tags: web-services, websocket, ip, port

Is that possible to connect windows application (C#) through domain IP and port like local computers? Or may I have to use web services?

> If web service is appropriate this kind of connectivity what is the
>   best language to build a web service?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to connect two different c# applications is [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can also use more primitive communication objects such as: [TCP Server/Client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C) , [UDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=vs.110).aspx) etc..